# Stored procedure, and select from two almost identical views

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, view

I have two views that returns the same columns, but different rows.

I am creating a stored procedure that uses these views. The stored procedure is big and searches across columns for rows that match.

Now, my wish is this: If i receive a bit parameter with the value 0, then i should get information from one view, if the parameter is 1 then i should get the information from another view.

I have understood that dynamic SQL is a bad idea, and the stored procedure i am working with is already quite complex. Recreating it to be dynamic is not an option.

I have also read about it being impossible to do this:

```
select * from @table
```

Because table names should be static, and not passed in to ex. a stored procedure by code.

What i am trying to accomplish is something like this:

```
SELECT TOP(@top) subtaskid,activityid FROM 
(CASE WHEN @allProjects=1 THEN view_project_all ELSE view_project_mine) v
```

however i get error messages saying "incorrect syntax near keyword 'CASE'. I realize that this question is closely related to dynamic sql, and variable views\tables questions all over stackoverflow, however i think that since my two tables are actually in the stored procedure this is more functionality than hack...

Question is this: Is there a way to set static variables so this one select can ask different views, according to parameter given?

Comment: Why dont you want duplicate code?What is the issue with that?Dynamic sql is another method. Also why to use views in the SP why dont you use the underlying tables directly and by maning of these views it seems that these are accessing same tables except the filtering mine vs all. You can expand the query and then make it in single statement and put the proper filtering. Can you post the view definitions?

Comment: The obvious reason for not wanting to duplicated code is refactoring and keeping our codebase as small as possible. If we were to change something in this procedure later we'd have to do at more than one place, which is a timeconsuming and costly affair. :) The reason using different views is that the tables in our database is huge, and has lots of information that is not needed, to go directly to tables would mean i'd have to write tons of logic to get this information out int he correct order. The view definitions are not possible to post since i work at a firm. Sorry :)

Comment: It might work in small solutions to always go directly to tables, and put all logic in sp's, but these view's are used in code, and not only in SP. To use directly to tables is also a weakness when it comes to adjusting the behaviour of the program. Consultants can change views and make the program work in different ways than it usually does, and this is worth gold. Programming directly to tables is usually not a good idea, and changing code in just two places, quickly multiplies to just a couple more, and there you have it... overall i completely disagree in your logic :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple way:

```
IF @allProjects = 1
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP(@top) subtaskid,activityid FROM view_project_all v;
END
ELSE
    SELECT TOP(@top) subtaskid,activityid FROM view_project_mine v;
BEGIN
END
```

If you wish, you can create a view that unions these tables then do your queries against that view:

```
SELECT subtaskid, activityid, 1 as allProjects FROM view_project_all
UNION ALL
SELECT subtaskid, activityid, 0 as allProjects FROM view_project_mine
```

Query against it:

```
SELECT TOP(@top) subtaskid,activityid FROM view_project_mine_all_union v WHERE allProjects = @allProjects;
```

Comment: See edits, create a new view with the union of the two views and a disciminator (allProjects).

Comment: That wont work either, this is because the values in the two seperated views are supposed to be seperate. If they were not i would not need two views :)

Comment: You can still create that third view, but only for the purposes of this SP.

Comment: i do not understand how the two would be seperated. There would need to be more selects then, to figure out how many records there is in each part of the unioned view, so that we only get the rows that belongs to each view? and does a union "sort" the rows so that rows from the first view comes first, and the last comes last, or are they mixed?

Comment: @BjørnØyvindHalvorsen. You would have three views: 1. `view_project_mine`, 2. `view_project_all`, 3. `view_project_union` (contains records from both 1 and 2). _mine and _all are unchanged. Continue to use them elsewhere without change. _all is like sticking 1 and 2 together and adding a field to determine the source (`[allProjects]`). You need to query one or the other but you only know which depending on the SP parameter `@allProjects`. Query the new view and filter on `[allProjects] = @allProjects`.

Comment: That was smart! I'll try it out!:) thnx =)

Comment: You don't even need to create the view - you can just union them together as a subquery if a new view offends you

Answer (score 2):

You can use an if

```
 if @allProjects = 1
       SELECT subtaskid,activityid FROM view_all_projects
 else
       SELECT subtaskid,activityid FROM view_project_mine
```

If this is a gross oversimplification of your issue, then you can put the results into a temporary table.

Or perhaps you can refine your projects view so that it includes the project owner and try

```
 SELECT subtaskid, activityId FROM view_projects
 WHERE (projectowner = USER) OR (@allprojects=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a simple if else loop

```
If @allProjects = 1
begin 
SELECT TOP(@top) subtaskid,activityid from view_project_all
end
else
begin 
SELECT TOP(@top) subtaskid,activityid from view_project_mine
end
```